# How to show multiple page links in google search for my react website

Tags: reactjs, google-search, google-search-console

I created a website and its live. I verified my website in [google search console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about). I also added sitemap and added it in `sitemap` of google search console tab. This is how my sitemap.txt look like (instead of my real domain i am sharing here links with dummy domain)

```
https://dummydomain.com/
https://dummydomain.com/gpservices
https://dummydomain.com/travelvaccinations
https://dummydomain.com/ivtherapies
https://dummydomain.com/bloodtests
https://dummydomain.com/policies
```

But when I search my website in google its still showing my website just as a single line result. I want that google can show my website in result as it is shown in picture below:

[image]

Also, I updated title and description for my website for better seo but its still not updated in google search result and its showing the previous version

Answer (score 0):

React makes fully client side app. It means that in react app there is no HTML, CSS files or content. Reactjs only creates javascript for everything. So when we request the server for website the server sends us the javascript bundle and the browser processes the bundle and then pages are generated by browser. This method is called client side rendering. CSR is not SEO friendly that's the biggest con of react apps. For Seo a react app looks empty just having one page with a one div element. To make your site SEO friendly you need to implement Server Side Rendering. There are frameworks which comes very handy for SSR, like Next.js, Gatsby etc. which generated html pages for ur websites on the server and sends them to the client.